# How to get OpenCV 4.1.0 on the yocto/poky warrior branch?

Tags: opencv, yocto, openembedded, nvidia-jetson

I've build a yocto/poky warrior branch image. As a standard it has OpenCV 3.4.5 via the openEmbedded [warrior branch](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/99799/) layer. But the [master branch](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/39865/) of openEmbedded has OpenCV 4.1.0, so I was wondering if I could just copy paste that folder into my warrior build to replace OpenCV 3.4.5? Can it be that simple?

Comment: Often this is the case  (at least when the version jump you make is a small one) but you might also end up in a situation where the new version depends on something that isn't available in any of your layers. Only one way to find out...

Comment: Yeah it needed some dependencies, so I guess in this case, it wasn't so simple. As I don't currently have the time or patience to fiddle around with it, I'll stick with OpenCV 3.4.5 for now. I *does* seem very doable though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it will not compile.

But if you go from warrior to `thud` (lower version), you will find a recipe for OpenCV 4.0.1 at https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/97501/